# writing unix script to increment the date

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to increment the year in one of the files which have values as below:

```
$$END_DATE=01/01/2020
$$END_DATE=01/01/2020
```

I need to increment the year by using a parameter. I am trying the below but getting an error. Could someone help me with this?

```
END_DATE1="$(grep END_DATE ABC.txt)"
echo "${END_DATE1}"
END_DATE=${END_DATE1} +%d/%m/%Y -d "${END_DATE1} +${END_DATE1} year"
echo "${END_DATE1}"|sed 's/\${END_DATE1 }/\${END_DATE}/'
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$ awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '/END_DATE/ {$NF++} 1' file
$$END_DATE=01/01/2021
$$END_DATE=01/01/2021
```

The `1` is an awk idiom to print each line. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info for more info

---

One of the issues you're having is that you're finding *all* the lines with an end date first, then you're trying to manipulate that data. You'll notice `END_DATE1` contains a multiline string, and `date -d` will have a problem with that.

Also, don't use ALLCAPS variable names, leave those as reserved by the shell.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In the file there are others lines present, i want to move on the incremented result to a variable could you please help me with this. I tried and it is displaying whole content of the file.

Comment: Use [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) and assign the result to a variable: `contents=$(awk -F/ -v OFS=/ '/END_DATE/ {$NF++} 1' file)`

Comment: i have tried this it is assigning the whole content instead of 01/01/2021

Comment: In END_DATE1="$(grep END_DATE ABC.txt)" the result i want is only 01/01/2020

Comment: i have tried END_DATE1="$(grep $END_DATE ABC.txt)" but it didnt work

Comment: You need to take a step back and forget about how you're trying to implement this. You have shown the input file. What output are you trying to achieve?

Comment: a file has various lines out of which there are 2 lines at different line numbers as $$END_DATE=01/01/2020. Here i need to increment the END_DATE +1 year every time i run command that the output should be as $$END_DATE=01/01/2021.

Comment: and the solution I provided does not work because it does not update the file in-place? If no, please explain more. If yes, use `gawk -i inplace -F/ -v OFS=/ '/END_DATE/ {$NF++} 1' file`

Comment: gawk -i inplace -F/ -v OFS=/ '/END_DATE/ {$NF++} 1' ABC.txt
 This is not working. I am working on a script which should read find $$END_DATE=01/01/2020 in ABC.txt and increment the year to $$END_DATE=2021. In order to get this i i was using below steps.

Comment: 1. Find the END_DATE -END_DATE1="$(grep END_DATE ABC.txt)"
2.echo "${END_DATE1}"
3.END_DATE=${END_DATE1} +%d/%m/%Y -d "${END_DATE1} +${END_DATE1} year"
 As it is finding the Whole of $$END_DATE it is not incrementing the date to 2021.